# Adobe Flex mobile App was not compatible in iphone while syncing itunes

Tags: macos, flash-builder, itunes

Adobe Flex mobile App was not compatible in iphone while syncing itunes.
created a flex mobile project using flash builder 4.5.  i got the IPA file by using release build in Flash. While syncing in iphone it shows not compatible. if anything wrong in certificates ?
Let us know the option to run the app in iphone

Comment: Did you include the iPhone's UDID in the provisioning file?

Comment: ya already i have done it.and also added my device name while creating provision file.Even thought i am getting it.